# How to use multiple decorator to a function and chain them together?

Tags: python, function, python-decorators

How can I make two decorators in Python that would do the following?

```
@check_zero_error
@check_numerator
def division(a, b):
    return a/b
```

'check_numerator' will reverse the numbers in case numerator is lesser than denominator.

'check_zero_error' will give check for the zero division error.

The expected output is:

```
division(1, 2)   # Output : 2.0

division(0, 2)   # Output : "Denominator can't be zero"
 
division(4, 1)   # Output : 4.0

division(5, 0)   # Output : "Denominator can't be zero"
```

My code is as below but I am not getting expected results:

```
def check_zero_error(division_func):
    def inner(a, b):
        if b == 0:
            return "Denominator can't be zero"
        else:
            division_func(a, b)
    return inner

def check_numerator(division_func):
    def inner(a, b):
        if a < b:
            a, b = b, a
        division_func(a, b)
    return inner


@check_zero_error
@check_numerator
def division(a, b):
    return a/b
       

print(division(1, 2))  # Expected output : 2.0
print(division(0, 2))  # Expected output : "Denominator can't be zero"
print(division(4, 1))  # Expected output : 4.0
```

Comment: When giving expected results, please also give the actual results,so we don't have to run the coed to get them

Comment: check_zero_error is executed  before check_numerator, so that's normal, 2 isn't 0, so you try the division, then the 2nd decorator swap them and you get the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your decorators method should `return` the result of the division

   ```
   def check_zero_error(division_func):
       def inner(a, b):
           if b == 0:
               return "Denominator can't be zero"
           else:
               return division_func(a, b)
       return inner

   def check_numerator(division_func):
       def inner(a, b):
           if a < b:
               a, b = b, a
           return division_func(a, b)
       return inner
   ```
2. Change the order of decorators, first `swap` (`check_numerator`) then if needed, THEN check the denominator with `check_zero_error`

   ```
   @check_numerator
   @check_zero_error
   def division(a, b):
       return a / b
   ```

Giving expected

```
print(division(1, 2))  # actual output : 2.0
print(division(0, 2))  # actual output : "Denominator can't be zero"
print(division(4, 1))  # actual output : 4.0
print(division(5, 0))  # actual output :  "Denominator can't be zero"
```